# How to get string in regular expression with space

Tags: javascript

This is my input as string

```
'controls: ["aa.bb.cc","dd.ee.ff"],elements: []'
```

I want to get the result of the data in the controls meaning :

```
    "aa.bb.cc","dd.ee.ff"
```

I tried pattern

```
     /.*(controls:.*).*/
```

but I didn't get all the result
I think my problem is becuase the new line

Comment: is 'controls' an array or should it be a string that looks like an array in the question? if its an array then you'll need to loop through the values. Can you post your full code?

Comment: all the input is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regEx

```
var c = 'controls: ["aa.bb.cc", "dd.ee.ff"], elements: []';

var match = c.match(/("[a-z.]+")/g);
// or c.match(/([a-z][a-z][.][a-z][a-z][.][a-z][a-z])/); 
// to strictly match letters . letters . letters
// or for a shorter match: c.match(/(\w+[.]\w+[.]\w+)/);
console.log(match); // an array of your values
```

EDIT:

if you only want to get the values in controls and not element, you can get the controls values out with the regEx `/controls: ([\["a-z., \]]+,)/g`

Comment: But if elements got values it will consider them as a match too: `'controls: ["aa.bb.cc", "dd.ee.ff"], elements: ["aa.bb.cc", "dd.ee.ff"]'`. ???

Comment: added regEx to get the controls values out

Comment: Good job, but it takes all the controls string like this: `controls: ["aa.bb.cc", "dd.ee.ff"],`.

Comment: yes that's right, then you can use my original regex on that new string to get the values you want

Comment: Yes right, and it will be `var match = c.match(([\["a-z., \]]+,)/g).match(/("[a-z.]+")/g)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply parse your input as a JSON object then loop throught the controls array:

```
var input='controls: ["aa.bb.cc", "dd.ee.ff"],
                        elements: []';

json = JSON.parse(input);
var controls=json.controls;
//then loop throught the controls values
for(var i=0;i<controls.length;i++){
   console.log(controls[i]);
}
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it with regular expression is it possible what is wrong in my code

Comment: You can't do it with the actual regex because with `/.*(controls:.*).*/` you can't get the value `"dd.ee.ff"`

Comment: Sorry buy why I can't do it with regular expression do I need to change the regular expression ?

Answer (score 2):

This might look like a very crude solution, but it works.

This expression will give you `aa.bb.cc` :

```
var res = str.match(/controls: \[(.*)\]/)[1].match(/\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"/)[1]
```

and this will give the next element i.e. `dd.ee.ff`

```
var res = str.match(/controls: \[(.*)\]/)[1].match(/\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"/)[2]
```

In general,

```
var str = "controls: [\"aa.bb.cc\",\"dd.ee.ff\"],elements: []";
var resLength = str.match(/controls: \[(.*)\]/)[1].match(/\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"/).length;
var res = str.match(/controls: \[(.*)\]/)[1].match(/\"(.*)\",\"(.*)\"/);
for (var i=1; i<resLength; i++) {
    console.log(res[i]);
}
```